# How to return float number with 2 digits after decimal point?

Tags: haskell, floating-point, formatting, printf, pretty-print

I have some simple function

```
f :: Float -> Float
f x = x

Prelude> f 5.00
5.0
```

Why not `5.00`? How can I achieve this?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve.  Looking at your questing it looks like you don't understand floating point numbers.

Answer (score 9):

If you want something from `base` then use `showGFloat`:

```
 > import Numeric
 > showGFloat (Just 2) 1.99438 ""
 "1.99"
 > :t showGFloat
 showGFloat :: RealFloat a => Maybe Int -> a -> ShowS
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [printf](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Text-Printf.html)

```
printf "%.2f" (f :: Float)
```

Comment: The code above throws some errors (`Couldn't match expected type Float with actual type Float -> Float`). So I used this one: `line n = printf "%.2f\n" $ f n`.

Comment: The link above doesn't work, currently, [printf](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Text-Printf.html) does

Answer (score 0):

Since: 4.7.0.0, one can use [showGFloatAlt](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Numeric.html#v:showGFloatAlt):

> This behaves as showFFloat, except that a decimal point is always guaranteed, even if not needed.

and the documentation for the old `showGFloat` doesn't say that a decimal point is always guaranteed.

(But I don't see any difference actually in my system:

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 8.6.4: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> import Numeric
Prelude Numeric> showGFloat (Just 2) 5.0 ""
"5.00"
Prelude Numeric> showGFloatAlt (Just 2) 5.0 ""
"5.00"
Prelude Numeric> showGFloat Nothing 5.0 ""
"5.0"
Prelude Numeric> showGFloatAlt Nothing 5.0 ""
"5.0"
```

I wonder why...)